# SQL Server Service Broker for monitoring DML changes

Tags: c#, sql-server, service-broker

What I want to do:

- Listen to DB insert/ update statements on X tables via a C# external application
- On each insert/ update I'd like to be notified
- after the notification I'd like to retrieve the inserted/ updated row

How I'm approaching this:

- Create a DML trigger for each table, that updates service broker queue on each after insert/ update
- After this, I'm not entirely clear on the approach. Mainly, how do I receive the notifications from the service broker queue?

From what I understand `SqlDependency` requires a query against which the changes are detected. Thus, do I specify a query against a target queue?

Thanks

Comment: What do you expect to find in the queue? A list of identifiers of rows that changed? Or a list of the actual changes? Either way, you're going to use a `receive` statement against the queue in which the trigger stashed the messge. You can also look at external activation (throw that term with 'service broker' into your favorite search engine for more details).

Comment: Ideally I'd have the actual changes in XML format, which I would use per requirements. Regarding external activation, my understanding of it is that it activates the exe file each time (I might be wrong ofcourse), where as ideally I'd like to have a constant connection to the db instance and get notified per DML trigger. Thus to clarify I where should  I use the Receive statement? Should it be defined in the SqlDependency query?

Answer (score 0):

SqlDependency is an abstraction that happens to use Service Broker under the hood to deliver the notifications. In this case, I think you can ignore it (it being SqlDependency)

I've actually implemented a similar system (queue up changes in broker). The broad strokes are:

1. Create a trigger for the types of changes that you want to capture (any of inserts/updates/deletes). The trigger will craft the XML message and send it to a Service Broker queue.
2. Consume these messages using something like `receive top(1000) cast(message_body as xml) from yourQueue`. Make sure you read up on best practices here (things like poison message handling, etc). You could wrap that all in a stored procedure and have your application call that.

Also, if you're eschewing activation, you're probably polling at some interval, chances are that when your application does poll, you're going to want to get all of the messages (or at least be notified that there are more). So you'll want to do the `receive` statement in a loop or do something clever like "Oh… I asked for at most 1000 and I got 1000. There are probably more!" so you know to go back immediately to process the queued messages. Let me know if you'd like me to elaborate on any of this.